# how to send data from separate computer to flask app

Tags: python, flask, post

My use case is I have a flaskapp running
The idea is it'll just display a static page (currently using PySimpleGUI) and upon receiving the information sent from the other computer (such as the name for e.g.) then it'll show the name as a QR code. (so perhaps a constant refresh on the GUI and changing upon receiving the data)

The code setup is this way currently

```
@app.route('/qrcode', methods=['GET'])
def displayQrCode():
    args = request.args 
    name = args.get('name') #
    
    try:
        img = qrcode.make(name)
        img.save('checkin-qrcode.png')
        # Display QR Code
        qrWindowThread = threading.Thread(target=qrCodeWindowShow)
        qrWindowThread.start()
        print(name)
        return 'Success'
    except RuntimeError:
        return 'Error in GET'
```

However, being new to Flask i am not sure how to send a string from a separate computer running jupyter notebook to this Flask app. Online tutorials show like having a form field page but i wish to not have an user input.

So for instance if the jupyter notebook code sends a post request to the ipaddress:5000 it should ideally show (correct me here: ipaddress:5000/qrcode?name=JohnDoe)
so the flask app would retrieve this JohnDoe and display it as a QR code. I can hardcode or manually access this page but how would i have it 'listen' to this /qrcode and then Get the value when it's sent. Or am i misunderstanding it all and I need to do it via another way?

Comment: Can you better explain what your code does at the moment and how is that not what you need? Is the server part working as intended?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Alright third time lucky, I think I understand what you want now. So your use case is a first computer that is displaying a GUI and running a flask server with an route that can take in a string.

There's a second computer that can send a http request to that route with a name and when that happens you want the GUI on the first computer to refresh to display a QR code of the name.

I'd solve this by having the qrcode route write that name to persistent storage. Could be anything sqlite db, an environment variable, a string in a file.

The first computer running the PySimpleGUI interface poles this persistent storage for changes, and if it sees a change then it renders a new QR code for that name and displays it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is what OP needs.

Comment: thanks! but yeah it's not the jupyter that needs to run. So the idea is it's when i execute the code it'll send / post it to a URL. I intend to do that to the flask app that's running. So it's the flask app that needs to 'listen' in that it should know when the code on the other computer has been executed. It's not a 24/7 thing just that when i boot it up to run the flask app listens and then displays the QR code based on the info it receives

Comment: Ah okay I misread your question, so you just want to get a string from a flask end point, one sec I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wait I think I missed the mark again, Do you want the first computer to constantly display a blank page, then in the background if that computer receives a http post the /qrcode, you want it to refresh it's page to display a qr code of the name that the end point was sent?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways available to do that:

1. REST API integration
2. Realtime data transmission using tornado or ??
3. Through a base origin for data transmission

Hope you get help with this.